# Xargs with command that has multiple parameters

Tags: linux, bash, openstack, xargs

I was advised to used these commands to get list of shutdown instances in Openstack and send them to start command as parameters:

```
nova list | grep SHUTOFF | cut '-d|' -f3 | xargs nova start
```

But it leads to error:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: shutdowninstance-2
```

If I use other commands with Xargs the the list is correct:

```
nova list | grep SHUTOFF | cut '-d|' -f3 | xargs echo
shutdowninstance-1 shutdowninstances-2
```

So first commands must be OK and the problem should be in the last part of command.
I guess that the reason it because the last command has parameter `start` next to it.
Syntax expected by Nova is `nova start nameofinstance`.

I studied many other questions about using Xargs here but could not find solution to this.

How should the command be changed to make it work?

EDIT: Using `xargs -t` gives this output:

```
nova start shutdowninstance-1 shutdowninstances-2
```

So the problem is probably that `nova start` accepts only one instance name at the time.

Can command given to me be adjusted to give only one parameter at the time?

Comment: I think there is something in your question that does not fit. Where does `tenant-test2` come from? When you used `echo`, no `tenant-test2` is displayed.

Comment: Fixed pasting error from question.

Comment: Please, use `xargs -t` to see the `nova` command really launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-I` option for `xargs`:

```
nova list | grep SHUTOFF | cut '-d|' -f3 | xargs -I '{}' bash -c 'nova start {}'
```

Alternatively you can loop over the results:

```
for i in $(nova list | grep SHUTOFF | cut '-d|' -f3); do nova start $i; done
```

Comment: Or just `xargs -n 1` to limit it to one argument at a time.  The `-I` does this implictly as well.  You don't need the `bash -c` wrapper for anything here; ...`| xargs -i nova start {}` is fine.